# More efficient way to write query with many nested ifs

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case, ssms

I am writing a query that uses historical averages to provide a simple projection of when future stages of a project will be complete. It first looks to see if any projects in that city have been completed recently and if so uses that average. If no projects in that city have been completed then this value will be NULL and it will use the average of the division (a group of cities). The logic of the query is:

If the stage previous to the one we are projecting has already been completed, add the city average for the current stage to the date the previous stage was completed. If there are no projects completed in that city then instead add the region average for the current stage to the date the previous stage was completed.

The logic is simple enough when the previous stage has already been completed. However, when the previous stage has not been completed then it must project the previous stages complete date following the same logic and then use that result to project the next stage. As you can imagine, this quickly becomes unruly. An example of the underlying data is below:

| Id | Div | City | Stage1 | Stage2 | Stage3 | Stage4 | Stage2AvgDiv | Stage2AvgCity | Stage3AvgDiv | Stage3AvgCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | SE | Houston | 2020-07-21 | 2020-07-31 | 2020-08-12 | 2020-08-21 | 15 | 18 | 27 | 16 |
| 456 | SE | Houston | 2022-06-17 | 2022-07-05 | NULL | NULL | 15 | 18 | 27 | 16 |
| 789 | SE | Beaumont | 2021-11-25 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 15 | NULL | 27 | NULL |

And an example of the result is below:

| Id | Div | City | Stage1 | Stage2 | Stage3 | Stage4 | Stage2AvgDiv | Stage2AvgCity | ProjectedStage2 | Stage3AvgDiv | Stage3AvgCity | ProjectedStage3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | SE | Houston | 2020-07-21 | 2020-07-31 | 2020-08-12 | 2020-08-21 | 15 | 18 | 2020-08-08 | 27 | 16 | 2020-08-16 |
| 456 | SE | Houston | 2022-06-17 | 2022-07-05 | NULL | NULL | 15 | 18 | 2022-07-05 | 27 | 16 | 2022-07-21 |
| 789 | SE | Beaumont | 2021-11-25 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 15 | NULL | 2021-12-10 | 27 | NULL | 2022-01-06 |

There are multiple Divisions as well as cities but this is all I could fit for an example. There is always at least a Division average but not always a City average (as seen in the example). If both are present it uses the city average. There is also always a Stage1 date at a minimum.

The query I have written is as follows:

```
,Stage2AvgDiv
,Stage2AvgCity

-- Project Stage2 complete date
,CASE WHEN [Stage2AvgCity] IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(day,[Stage2AvgCity],[Stage1])
    ELSE DATEADD(day,[Stage2AvgDiv],[Stage1])
END AS ProjectedStage2


,Stage3AvgDiv
,Stage3AvgCity

-- Project Stage3 complete date
,CASE WHEN ([Stage2] IS NOT NULL) THEN
    CASE WHEN ([Stage3AvgCity] IS NOT NULL) THEN DATEADD(day,[Stage3AvgCity],[Stage2])
    ELSE DATEADD(day,[Stage3AvgDiv],[Stage2])
    END
 ELSE
    CASE WHEN [Stage2AvgCity] IS NOT NULL THEN
        CASE WHEN ([Stage3AvgCity] IS NOT NULL) THEN DATEADD(day,[Stage2AvgCity]+[Stage3AvgCity],[Stage1])
        ELSE DATEADD(day,[Stage2AvgCity]+[Stage3AvgDiv],[Stage1])
        END
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN ([Stage3AvgCity] IS NOT NULL) THEN DATEADD(day,[Stage2AvgCity]+[Stage3AvgCity],[Stage1])
        ELSE DATEADD(day,[Stage2AvgDiv]+[Stage3AvgDiv],[Stage1])
        END
    END
 END AS ProjectedStage3
```

The query works fine however in the real data I have 9 stages as opposed to 3-4. Therefore, the nesting is increasing exponentially each time and has created a query so large maintenance will be all but impossible. I was hoping someone might have a suggestion on how I could minimize this length since it is such a repetitive query. I tried looking into functions and stored procedures but didn't have any luck.

Comment: The reason this is so painful is because your design violates 1NF which what is called "repeating groups". When you have things like Stage1AvgCity, Stage2AvgCity you have created a nightmare. Consider how much work that will be to add a new stage. You would have to change literally every single query that touches the table. This should be two tables. With a properly normalized structure this type of query is simple.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the response however I must admit I'm failing to see how 1NF would help me achieve the same result with a less lengthy query. If I were to break the underlying data into three separate tables with 1) ID info, and stage dates; 2) CityAvg's by stage; and 3) DivisionAvg's by stage; the logic appears the same to me. Could you please clarify what the logic would be if the tables were in 1NF as you suggest.

Comment: I am NOT suggesting you normalize this to only 1NF. I am suggesting that the reason your query is difficult is because of the lack of normalization. If this was properly normalized you could easily do a cross tab or conditional aggregation to produce the results you are looking for.,